# Integral closure of $\mathbb{C}[x^5, y^5, x^4y]$ in its ring of fractions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $A = \mathbb{C}[x^5, y^5, x^4y]$. I want to find its integral closure in $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$, i.e. the normalization of $A$.

As given in the comments, the answer is $\mathbb{C}[x^5, y^5, x^4y, x^3y^2, x^2y^3, xy^4, y^5]$, but I still don't know why.

$S^{G} =\mathbb{C}[x^5, y^5, x^4y, x^3y^2, x^2y^3, xy^4, y^5]$  is the ring of invariants of $S = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ by cyclic group of order 5.

That means that $S$ is integral over $S^G$.

Comment: While $x$ is in the integral closure of $A$, it is not in $\operatorname{Frac}(A).$ Are you asking which elements of $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathbb C[x,y])=\mathbb C(x,y)$ are in the integral closure of $A?$

Comment: @user:7933 Oh, you are right, $T^5=y^5$ doesn't have a solution in Frac(A). I'm asking which elements of Frac(A) are integral over A.

Comment: The integral closure of $A$ is $\overline A=\mathbb{C}[x^5,y^5,x^4y,xy^4,x^3y^2,x^2y^3]$. (This follows from standard results on the integral closure of monomial algebras.)

Comment: @user26857 Ok, will try to find it in Atyah-McDonald's book.

Comment: $Frac(A) = \Bbb{C}(x^5,y/x)$ and the subring of $Frac(A)$ of holomorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}^2$ is $\Bbb{C}[(x^{5-k} y^k)_{k \in 0 \ldots 5}]$ which is integrally closed

Comment: @reuns Could you explain why $Frac(A)$ is $\Bbb{C}(x^5,y/x)$?

Comment: $Frac(A) = \mathbb{C}(x^5, y^5, x^4y)=\mathbb{C}(x^5, y/x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have $(x^2y^3)^5=(x^5)^2\cdot(y^5)^3$.
This means that $x^2y^3$ is integral over $A$

That means that the answer contains all monomials of degree 5, which is $S^G$, where $G = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Algebra $S^G$ is normal, because $S$ is a UFD hence normal.